# Installed trigger causing permissions error for Browser.inputBox even when script is authorized

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google spreadsheet with a function: `appendComment` that is attached to the onEdit installable trigger for the sheet.

Permissions for the sheet are set to both link sharing (anyone with link has edit permission) and specific users with edit access.

1. setting up:
   I have a menu item added in the `onOpen` trigger which starts the script permission process, giving permission for the scripts to run for that user. It is a simple MsgBox call inside a function called `getAuthorization`. To initiate authorization for the scripts in the sheet, the user selects the only item from the "SCG" menu, which initiates the process.
2. the problem:
   After authorizing the script, I make the trigger fire by clicking on a checkbox in a cell on the sheet (the `appendComment` function only operates when I click in that column), I get a permissions error that looks like this:

> You do not have permission to call prompt (line 30, file "")

This is infuriating... can't find this problem and its resolution anywhere.

Both `Browser.inputBox` and `ui.prompt` cause the same error.

Here is a simple reproduction of the problem in a google-sheet for anyone who wants to take a look:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WxVTulbqT8dtUlHEf_TW_Jaus5a1GSfXnjgdoWYhrls/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Clarifying comment:
To reproduce the issue, you need to first select the "Activate Scripts" menu item from the custom menu "SCG" in the sheet. This initiates the authorization process for the scripts.  You need to grant authorization to the scripts in order for the triggers to function.

Comment: See here: https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36756302 `Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
Installable triggers are not allowed to show HTML or prompts to the user for input unless the trigger user is the same as the user using the sheet/doc.`

Comment: OK this is unfortunate. Can you suggest an event I can attach such a trigger to? I want to prompt user for input, append date, username etc. and append to existing values in a cell to control formatting.  What trigger/event combo can I use for this?

Comment: You should be able to show an alert or a toast message to remind the the user to fill out necessary fields in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I want to prompt the user for input.  What trigger can I use to do that?  I don't want to just alert them, but to collect information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the result I was going for... controlled comments history with easy comment entry by users on a sheet... I did away with the prompt boxes and just used the adjacent cell instead.

Ended up putting my function in the onEdit trigger.

No box neededed, no permission issues, works even better than with the checkbox.